# Drag to change referenced cell in Google Sheets as Libre Office Calc does?

Tags: google-sheets

In LOC when double clicking cell A1 that has the formula '=B1*C1', both B1 and C1 have a coloured border that is drag-able. Dragging B1's border to D1 now makes the formula in A1 '=D1*C1'.

In Sheets when double clicking cell A1 that has the formula '=B1*C1', both B1 and C1 have a dashes coloured border that is not drag-able.

Is there a way to replicate the LOC functionality in Google Sheets?